# Socket io private messages using expressjs nodejs mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, socket.io

I'm struggling with socket.io to make a chat app with the users that are logged in in my app. I followed the beginner course and I could make a private chat app, but the users aren't the ones that are in my database or they have to create a username to connect to the chat app.

In my search I found this one - 
[Realtime app with Vue, Laravel, Socket.io and Redis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nm8V8rXurbs&index=1&list=PLkZU2rKh1mT-Wd6vVwSLjf02caq57xyoO) (He's making a similar app using Laravel)

I want the exact same app but using nodejs mongoose express.
Can you help me with some references or tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some resources that might -

- [Make A Real-Time Chat Room using Node Webkit, Socket.io, and MEAN](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-realtime-room-chat-app-using-node-webkit-socket-io-and-mean)
- [Simple Chat Application using NodeJS and Socket.IO](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/777640/Simple-chat-application-using-NodeJS-and-Socket-IO)

Please start with any of these and be more specific with what extra feature you're trying to implement. (code would be very helpful)

Couldn't understand what do you mean by the users not in database bit.